# CSS calc percentage divided by x then minus 1 px?

Tags: css

Im use CSS calc to make 7 items the correct width to sit side by side:

```
width: calc(100% / 7);
```

This works fine in most browsers but sometimes IE rounds up, making the last item clear to the next line. How can I subtract 1px from the width?

```
width: calc((100% / 7) -1px);
```

Comment: This should work `width: calc((100% / 7) - 1px);`

Comment: Always include a space before and after the + and -. The spaces are optional for / and *.

Comment: Why not directly write `width: 14.285713%`

Comment: @Justinas because tomorrow it might be 8 or 9 items, it's simpler to edit the css. BTW i think you should not specify any width at all, use flexbox instead.

Comment: @Justinas it's easier to quickly understand the intent of the calc formula by displaying it as 100% / 7 another devoloper can look at it and instantly guess they want to fit up to 7 elements side by side. Likewise changing it to 8 is very trivial. Computing the result won't save much performance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better support than Flexbox, use **CSS Tables** as a solution and avoid the whole `calc` requirement in the first place.

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) is good as far back as **IE8**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bada55;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I downvoted it because it assumes too much about the question. "CSS tables have better support than Flexbox" is by no standards an answer to "How can I subtract 1px from the width using calc", and only qualifies as an answer because a meta-discussion between this and other answers was created. If the other answers would be deleted, this answer would be entirely useless to someone looking towards fixing their `calc` issue. In this case it helped the questioner, but that doesn't make it a generally useful answer.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I understand but will you be downvoting the flexbox answer? Yes, this isn't a direct **answer** but it is a **solution**. :)

Comment: You should recommend flexbox, and suggest to only use tables if you really need the browser support. It would be sad if people found this and used old style CSS just because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I'm by no means a friend of the flexbox answer, however it doesn't assume knowing content from other questions like yours does, plus it states that they're suggesting a different solution than the one originally proposed. That said, your answer is not a solution either, as you completely neglect the *problem* - people finding this question in the future in the attempt to remedy their `calc` problems won't be helped by your answer, which is what votes should reflect.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: @peternyc I have no need to recommend flexbox as other answers already had.  I merely pointed out that other solutions have better support. I'm a big proponent of flexbox but I don't necessarily use it in in every instance when other methods work just as well, regardless of how *old* they are.

Answer (score 3):

Always include a space before and after the operands (i.e `/`, `*`, `-`, `+`). Here is a working example.

**Note:** I have used `-2px`, since i have `border-right` and `border-left` of `1px` each.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would be an better option, but check browser compatibility before proceeding.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
.wrapper div {
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: calc((100% / 7) - 2px);
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you circumvent the `calc` problem by using `flexbox`.

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

#parent > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If you really need better browser support you can look into CSS Tables.

Comment: Browser support is better for calc isnt it? http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: `calc` is 'old school' thinking. you should use `flexbox` instead. and if you care about old browser, use a [polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility).